# Plotting values directly in plot function

Tags: gnuplot

Im currently plotting all my data by passing values from an array into a file and reading it.

Is it possible somehow to enter points directly into the plot function?

Something like: `plot {{x....}{y....}}`

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yes that's possible

```
plot "-" u 1:2 w l
x1 y1
x2 y2
x3 y3
x4 y4
e
```

Comment: One downside of this approach is that (as far as I have been able to find), using replot with this forces you to enter the data again ... even using the `volatile` keyword doesn't seem to help (I'm not aware of any way around that other than sending the data to a temporary file).  BUT, you can plot your data, set some things and then issue a `refresh` to update whatever you set (grid, labels, etc)...

Comment: I see the issue in case of `replot`, but in my case it will not be neccessary, anyhow its good to know incase i will be using the functionality. The most essential thing right now is skipping the step where i copy data into a file and plot it.

Comment: I assumed that `replot` would not be a problem, it's just good to have it written down in case somebody else comes stumbling on this from a google search or whatever.

Answer (score 1):

This is something that I have had cause to use on occasion...If processing your data is quick, only outputs one dataset and your system supports popen, sometimes it makes sense to have your processing script run as a slave of gnuplot (instead of the other way around).  For example:

```
 #!/usr/bin/env gnuplot
 #This is script is called process_and_plot.gp
 plot "<my_processing_application unprocessed_input.file" u 1:2 w l
```

In this case you can do your processing and get output in one command:  `./process_and_plot.gp` ...  Of course, this approach is pretty restrictive (passing commandline arguments doesn't really work without some clever tricks, my_processing_application must only write a gnuplot dataset to stdout, etc).  In most cases you'll probably want to use @RaphaelRoth's answer, I just wanted to point you toward a slightly different way of thinking about the problem.

Comment: Thanks, i did not consider that option, but im thankful to add it into my portfolio of solutions. Right now @RaphaelRoth's solution seems straightforward for me to implement quite easily.